How to calculate standard error of a partial sum of balls in bins
As part of an experiment, I independently throw $M$ balls with equal probability into $N$ bins, resulting in $m_i$ balls in the $i$th bin.  I then randomly choose $n$ of those $N$ bins and sum the number of balls within them. I need to know the expectation value of the sum and its standard error, for error propagation during analysis of the final results.
The expectation value is obviously $$\sum_n{m_i} = M\frac{n}{N} \ .$$
How do I calculate the standard error?

edit: so to answer my own question, it is a multinomial distribution and the variance of any bin is $$\operatorname{Var}(X_i) = \frac{M}{N}\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)$$ and the covariance of any two distinct bins is $$\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j) = -\frac{M}{K^2} \ . $$  The variance of a sum across $n$ bins is $$\operatorname{Var} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n{X_k}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n{\sum_{j=1}^n{\operatorname{Cov} (X_i,X_j)}} \ ,$$ which evaluates to $$\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n{X_k}\right) = n\frac{M}{N}\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right) - n(n-1)\frac{M}{N^2}$$ and then just take the square root for standard deviation.

How is standard error defined?

Probably standard deviation.

It's not clear what you are looking for here.  Are the values $(M,N)$ known or unknown?  If one or both is unknown, then maybe you are looking to estimate one or both (or some function of the two) by means of a sample?  If both are already known, then what is it you are hoping to estimate?

Yes, standard deviation.  $M$, $N$, and $n$ are known; the actual sum is unknown.  I have an expected value for it, but need to know how confident to be in that estimation.

Well, being  or not being in one of the special bins is just a binomial process with probability $\frac nN$, so...
